# Ace and Monaco for .NET C# on my own site?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

Is there any code completion support for the Ace code editor with C# and .NET classes?

Is it possible to use Microsoft Monaco editor on private sites outside Azure?

Other web based editors out there with code completion, intellisense, coloring for .NET C# I can use freely or buy for a smaller amount (~$20)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ace code editor does not contain any plugins that would provide C# Intellisense. Writing such a plugin would require using [OmsniSharp](https://github.com/omnisharp), and it would be a significant undertaking.

I know this information because I'm a C# developer and I developed a [Tern Plugin for Ace](http://sevin7676.github.io/Ace.Tern/demo.html#javascript) *(basically JavaScript Intellisense)*. Also, [I contributed](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/commits?author=sevin7676) SQL Server mode and support for region folding in all C-style languages to the ACE editor.

Currently the Monaco editor is used in a [few places](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ARichNewJavaScriptCodeEditorSpreadingToSeveralMicrosoftWebSites.aspx) by Microsoft including Azure, TypeScript playground, and VS Code. VS Code just became open source last week, and [I'm working on getting information](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/446) about how to run the Monaco Editor in a web site.